# Can I have two dictionaries working at the same time in OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, dictionary

Is there a way to have two dictionaries working at the same time on Mac OS X Lion?

So, whatever language I choose to write, it will check spell that or show meaning of words when I press `Ctrl-Cmd-D`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionary already works like this.

> [image]

Here, *Dictionary*, *Thesaurus* and *Wikipedia* are just all the "dictionaries" that contain an entry for the highlighted term. The OS X default dictionary is only available in English. You need to get additional dictionaries for other languages.

Just to prove it, I installed a German thesaurus and looked up a term:

> [image]

---

Regarding spell checking, this needs to be supported by the application you're using. In Pages, it's customizable in the document inspector. Select *All* in the *Language* section shown below to spell-check terms in all supported languages:

[image]

This setting applies to *selected text*, just like e.g. making text bold. This way, you can declare e.g. English parts and German parts of your document.

OS X's spell checking does *not* use Dictionary data (which would be horrible for non-English users, since there's only an English dictionary). Don't expect to be able to enhance this feature by adding dictionaries to *Dictionary.app*.

Comment: and how do I install other dictionaries as you say?

Comment: @Mike Download and install them. I was successful by googling *Deutsches Wörterbuch Mac OS* (German for *German dictionary Mac OS*) and looking through the results, so you could try that. Asking for any specific language will probably be considered *too localized* on this site.